# Encoding of colon (:) with Google Cloud Endpoints, Android Studio

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, google-cloud-endpoints

When passing a string parameter to the AppEngine Dev Server (version 1.9.15) from the generated  client library (built with the default Android Studio 1.02 / Gradle configuration), I found that colons in string parameters are not URL encoded.  The colons are then interpreted as part of the request structure by the dev server, which returns a 404.  I haven't tested this in a production environment.

I don't know if this is simply a bug in the cloud endpoints library or the dev server, but would be appreciative if anyone has a fix or a work around.  Manually URLencoding and decoding the parameter works, but isn't very elegant.  Thanks!

Examples:

`[Api].[method]("param:with:colon").execute().getItems();`

produces the request:

`GET /_ah/api/.../param:with:colon HTTP/1.1`

and the response:

`HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found`

A string parameter without the colon works normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workaround here is turning this parameter from path parameter to query parameter by providing an explicit path attribute in @ApiMethod annotation.

In the following example code. By default, paramenter "content" is  a path parameter. ( default path here is "sayhi/{content}")

```
 @ApiMethod(name = "sayHi", httpMethod = "get")
  public HelloGreeting sayHi(@Named("content") String content) throws Exception {
    return new HelloGreeting(content);
  }
```

After adding "path" attribute, "content" parameter will be passed and extracted via/from query parameter.

```
 @ApiMethod(name = "sayHi", httpMethod = "get", path="sayhi")
  public HelloGreeting sayHi(@Named("content") String content) throws Exception {
    return new HelloGreeting(content);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks!  That is a great help.  It still seems strange that path parameters aren't clean by default, though.